# MSSQL schema change to account for uniqueness across two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following 3 tables, and I am trying to get the schema changed to account for a uniqueness for [Check].FromCompanyID, [Check].ToCompanyID and [ActivityToCheck].ActivityID. Other than adding the two FromCompanyID and ToCompanyID to the [ActivityToCheck] table, how could I go about modifying to schema so I can add a unique constraint on one of tables?

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Activity](
    [ActivityID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [EndDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL
    --<OTHER COLUMNS>
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Check](
    [CheckID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CheckNumber] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [CheckDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [CheckDescription] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FromCompanyID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ToCompanyID] [int] NOT NULL
    --<OTHER COLUMNS>
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActivityToCheck](
    [ActivityToCheckID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ActivityID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CheckID] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

EDIT: would a schema bound view be a reasonable way of ensuring uniqueness:

```
CREATE VIEW TestView 
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
SELECT ActivityToCheckID, CheckNumber, CheckID, FromCompanyID, ToCompanyID, ActivityID, AmountPaid
FROM [dbo].[Check] c
inner join [dbo].ActivityToCheck a on c.CheckID = a.CheckID
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX testindex on TestView (FromCompanyID, ToCompanyID, ActivityID)
GO
```

Thanks,

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the `ActivityToCheck` to be unique per `CheckID` is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, the ActivityToCheck needs to be Unique across FromCompanyID, ToCompanyID and ActivityID, basically what I am trying to avoid is two people from the FromCompany adding the same ActivityID to several different checks going to ToCompany.

Answer (score 0):

You must use following trigger for `dbo.Check` Table :

```
CREATE TRIGGER YourTriggerName ON dbo.[check]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT *
                FROM Inserted i
                INNER JOIN dbo.ActivityToCheck a1 ON i.CheckId = a1.CheckId
                INNER JOIN dbo.ActivityToCheck a2 ON a2.ActivityId = a1.ActivityId
                INNER JOIN dbo.[CHECK] c ON c.CheckId = a2.CheckId AND c.FromCompanyId=i.FromCompanyId AND c.ToCompanyId=i.ToCompanyId) BEGIN
            RAISERROR('Your information is duplicate.',16,1)
            RETURN;
    End

    INSERT INTO dbo.[check] (CheckNumber, CheckDate, CheckDescription, FROMCompanyId, ToCompanyId)
    SELECT CheckNumber, CheckDate, CheckDescription, FROMCompanyId, ToCompanyId
    FROM Inserted

END
```

also you must create instead of update trigger for `dbo.Check` table, if FromCompanyId or ToCompanyId editable and can change.

Comment: Those tables could potentially become very large, I would like to stay away from doing several joins every time I insert a record.

Comment: Trigger effect on Insert record on table and related to amount of insert transaction on your table. and not related to amount of record in the table.